# How masking of sensitive data is achieved using slf4j framework?

Tags: slf4j

I wanted to mask the sensitive data like username/password using an slf4j framework. Immediate help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Try this one.
1. First of all, we should create a class for handling our logs (each row)

```
public class PatternMaskingLayout extends PatternLayout {

private Pattern multilinePattern;
private List<String> maskPatterns = new ArrayList<>();

public void addMaskPattern(String maskPattern) { // invoked for every single entry in the xml
    maskPatterns.add(maskPattern);
    multilinePattern = Pattern.compile(
            String.join("|", maskPatterns), // build pattern using logical OR
            Pattern.MULTILINE
    );
}

@Override
public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
    return maskMessage(super.doLayout(event)); // calling superclass method is required
}

private String maskMessage(String message) {
    if (multilinePattern == null) {
        return message;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(message);
    Matcher matcher = multilinePattern.matcher(sb);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group().contains("creditCard")) {
            maskCreditCard(sb, matcher);
        } else if (matcher.group().contains("email")) {
            // your logic for this case
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
private void maskCreditCard(StringBuilder sb, Matcher matcher) {
    //here is our main logic for masking sensitive data
    String targetExpression = matcher.group();
    String[] split = targetExpression.split("=");
    String pan = split[1];
    String maskedPan = Utils.getMaskedPan(pan);
    int start = matcher.start() + split[0].length() + 1;
    int end = matcher.end();
    sb.replace(start, end, maskedPan);
}
```

}

2. The second step is we should create appender for logback into logback.xml

   ```
   <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
   <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
       <layout class="com.bpcbt.micro.utils.PatternMaskingLayout">
           <maskPattern>creditCard=\d+</maskPattern> <!-- SourcePan pattern -->
           <pattern>%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n%ex</pattern>-->
       </layout>
   </encoder>
   ```
3. Now we can use logger into our code

   log.info("card context set for creditCard={}", creditCard);
4. As a result, we will see

   one row from logs

   card context set for creditCard=11111******111

without these options, our logs would be like this row

```
card context set for creditCard=1111111111111
```

Comment: So I know this is a pretty old thread, but does anyone know where Utils.getMaskedPan(pan); comes from? What library has to be imported for that?

Comment: Utils.getMaskedPan(pan) - this is my own method ) with the custom realization of mask sensitive data.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this library will helpfull: [owasp-security-logging](https://github.com/javabeanz/owasp-security-logging)

It related to [OWASP Security Logging Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Security_Logging_Project)
 and provide related features:

```
LOGGER.info("userid={}", userid);  
LOGGER.info(SecurityMarkers.CONFIDENTIAL, "password={}", password);
```

The intent is to produce the following output in the log:

```
2014-12-16 13:54:48,860 [main] INFO - userid=joebob
2014-12-16 13:54:48,860 [main] [CONFIDENTIAL] INFO - password=***********
```

More you can find in [Wiki](https://github.com/javabeanz/owasp-security-logging/wiki)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using Java/Groovy. In your log4j2.xml, add something like:

```xml
<PatternLayout pattern="%mm"/>
```

then take that pattern and create a converter for it:

```java
@Plugin(name = 'maskLog', category = 'Converter')
@ConverterKeys(['mm'])
class MaskLogConverter extends LogEventPatternConverter {
    
    private static final String NAME = 'mm'
    
    private MaskLogConverter(String[] options) {
        super(NAME, NAME)
    }
    
    static LogMaskingConverter newInstance(final String[] options) {
        return new LogMaskingConverter(options)
    }
    
    @Override
    void format(LogEvent event, StringBuilder outputMessage) {
        String message = event.message//.formattedMessage
        
        // Do your masking logic here
        
        outputMessage.append(message)
    }
}
```

Inside that class you can mask, transform, parse, etc. accordingly.

Comment: Hi, Cant we take private static final String NAME = 'mm' from application.properties file?

Answer (score -9):

The framework itself won't do the masking, nor should you expect it to. It's a very bad practice to pass confidential information to a reporting system. In your `log.info()` call, make sure to substitute the password with asterisks. There is no point in masking the username because you might as well not log anything.

```
log.info("Successful login: {0} ********", username);
```

Comment: You advise is bad because doing this manually is error prone. It is better to have a common generic solution for this to make sure nothing is missed.

Comment: In my experience, you have to manually inspect every potential exposure of confidential data as part of your auditing process. Again, this is not the responsibility of the logging framework.

Comment: No, log4j does support overwriting password by asterics.

Comment: Checking every log call for sensitive data leak in a big application is impractical and you can never guarantee human errors.