# Masking sensitive data before getting logged - log4j

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, data-masking

For logging purposes, instead of using `toString()` method, Jackson's `writeValueAsString(object)` method has been used in the project I have been working for.

```
LOGGER.info(mapper.writeValueAsString(object));
```

Now, I got the requirement to mask the sensitive information like passwords and credit card numbers in logs. If `toString()` is being used, I could have removed those sensitive data from the `toString()` method. But in my case, I could not find such simple yet correct way of getting my problem solved. I am not in a situation where I can change the entire thing to use `toString()` too.

I read that by using `%replace` method, I can replace the data which I don't need to be logged in using a predefined pattern. But all the sensitive data that need to be masked wont follow a single pattern.

I tried by intercepting the log event, look for the particular information and mask them(Using a class which implements `LogEventFactory`). Even though it is a working solution, I don't think that it is a good solution since looking for the data in big strings every time is gonna cost.

Is there any way that I haven't come across yet to get my problem resolved? Is the approach with `%replace` is the way to go? If so, how?

Comment: I'm interested in this. Did you find a good way to solve your problem?

Comment: try this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/61360391/7697901

Answer (score -1):

I think there are three ways to solve your problem which you all covered. Most efficient way is to prevent log sensitive data to logger, which you need a bunch of work to do.

And the second way is to modify Appender. By extend log4j Appenders, you modify the LogEvent.

And last way is to modify the PatternLayout. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2461726/1820217).

```
public class CardNumberFilteringLayout extends PatternLayout {
    private static final String MASK = "$1++++++++++++";
    private static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})([0-9]{9,15})");

    @Override
    public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
        if (event.getMessage() instanceof String) {
            String message = event.getRenderedMessage();
            Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(message);

            if (matcher.find()) {
                String maskedMessage = matcher.replaceAll(MASK);
                @SuppressWarnings({ "ThrowableResultOfMethodCallIgnored" })
                Throwable throwable = event.getThrowableInformation() != null ? 
                        event.getThrowableInformation().getThrowable() : null;
                LoggingEvent maskedEvent = new LoggingEvent(event.fqnOfCategoryClass,
                        Logger.getLogger(event.getLoggerName()), event.timeStamp, 
                        event.getLevel(), maskedMessage, throwable);

                return super.format(maskedEvent);
            }
        }
        return super.format(event);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Suppose I want to get MASK field from application.properties with atValue annotation. Once i add atValue that fields not getting loaded. Any idea on how to load properties?

Comment: How is the CardNumberFilteringLayout class supposed to be hooked up with the logger?